# When using Meteorjs' autoform, can I set a field allowing the user to take a photo?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

In the schema declaration I have:

```
CollectionName.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({


 issue: {
  type: String,
  label: "Describe the issue you noticed",
  max:256
},
location: {
  label: "Place a marker on your approximate location",
  type: String,
  autoform: {
    type: 'map',
    afFieldInput: {
      type: 'map',
      autolocate: true,
      zoom:16
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to allow a user to take a picture on this insert form

```
{{> quickForm collection="CollectionName" id="inserttoCollection" type="insert"}}
```

I'd like to be able to let an individual not only document the location of an issue but take a picture of what issue was noticed.

**My question**: How do I set up a field properly so that it allows a user to take and upload a photo.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the areas where Meteor shines - isomorphic APIs that work across desktop and mobile browsers.

You'll want to `meteor add mdg:camera`, add a button to your form, and set its click handler to run `MeteorCamera.getPicture()`.

Read more at https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:camera

Comment: It's not clear how `mdg:camera` integrates with `autoform` package.  Aka, once you take the picture, there needs to be a hook to re-render the form in place (*state maintained).  This is an issue using Meteoric as I've discovered.